# AccountManager throwing UnsupportedOperationException: getAuthTokenLabel

Tags: android, authentication, android-account

I am calling the code below in an Android app (for authenticating against Google App Engine, think that is by-the-by):

```
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
accountManager.getAuthToken(mAccount, "ah",null, false, new GetAuthTokenCallback(), null);
```

In `GetAuthTokenCallback()` this error is thrown:

```
android.accounts.AuthenticatorException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getAuthTokenLabel not supported
```

The authentication process stops there.

The odd thing is that it runs on a Android 5.5.1 device perfectly; the UnsupportedOperationException only error occurs on a 6.0.1 device.

I have runtime permission request for `GET_ACCOUNTS` which I think I need but suspect the error stems from this and Marshmellow's permissions systems.

```
@TargetApi(23)
private boolean haveGetAccountPermission() {
    Log.i(TAG, "haveGetAccountPermission()");
    int hasWriteContactsPermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS);
    if (hasWriteContactsPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[] {Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS},
                REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but I've found that creating a new account immediately before executing `getAuthToken()` throws this exception.

In my case, I was trying to rename an account, and I found that if I first execute `getAuthToken()` with the old account and *then* create a new account with its contents, the exception would no longer be thrown.

I'm suspicious that this may be a bug in Marshmallow.